# Creating multiple cursors

Tags: python, mysql

Is there a shorthand for doing the following?

```
    # need 3 cursors for reading and writing
    self.cursor1 = self.conn.cursor()
    self.cursor1.execute("SET NAMES utf8")
    self.cursor1.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
    self.cursor1.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')

    self.cursor2 = self.conn.cursor()
    self.cursor2.execute("SET NAMES utf8")
    self.cursor2.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
    self.cursor2.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')

    self.cursor3 = self.conn.cursor()
    self.cursor3.execute("SET NAMES utf8")
    self.cursor3.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
    self.cursor3.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
```

Basically, I need three cursors for reading and writing in a script, and I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
cursor_n = self.cursor1.clone()
```

If something like that exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this better?

```
self.cursor = []
for n in range(3):
    self.cursor.append(self.conn.cursor())
    self.cursor[n].execute("SET NAMES utf8")
    self.cursor[n].execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
    self.cursor[n].execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
```

or (I suppose cursor() is a class):

```
class my_cursor(self.conn.cursor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.execute("SET NAMES utf8")
        self.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
        self.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')

self.cursor1 = my_cursor()
self.cursor2 = my_cursor()
self.cursor3 = my_cursor()
```